# HDMI "No Signal" when plugged to my monitor

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspbian-lite

I have very interesting problem when i plug my HDMI to my monitor. It shows "No Signal" and I don't know from what is coming. Hope somebody know an resolve for this issue and answer me. First when I bought it, I installed rasbian lite and monitor worked, then i decided to reinstall the raspberry , but second time it says " no signal", I tryed to headless start and worked. Also before second reinstall I decided to change my raspberry case and added new one with fan which I connected to the GPIO pins, but finally I decided to use the normal case for now, because temperature was good and when I tryed to plug HDMI , this happened. Also I don't have micro hdmi to hdmi I use Micro HDMI Adapter, to connect it but i don't know how first time it works and second time doesn't work. I think something limits the Voltage coming from the HDMI port and can't be powered or something other. I tryed with hdmi_safe 1 // hdmi_force_hotplug=1 // config_hdmi_boost=4 // hdmi_group=2 and still no result. Hope somebody helps me. I'll be very glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the problem with new cable without adapter, but much smaller than my old cables, I think when your cable is long, the power supply won't work. Also keep in mind that the hdmi cable need to be plugged, before you plug power cable.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem before and managed to solve it by doing the following:

1. Connect the pi to an HDMI monitor by using micro HDMI-HDMI cable.
2. Power up the pi using at least a 2.1A adapter

If this didnt solve the issue, try to flash a clean raspbian to the SD card once more.

Comment: I already reinstall it like 2-5 times, so you think its from the hdmi adapter ? Because its actually new one i think the voltage is low to power this adapter and go through the cable.

Comment: I would suspect the HDMI adapter to be the issue because I have bad experience with them, especially cheap ones. Try using an actual micro HDMI cable